# Python subprocess arguments containing both single and double quotes

Tags: python, subprocess, quotes, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm using Python 3.7 and trying to open a subprocess that calls an API that is very picky about the formatting of its arguments. The command isn't super complex but one of the arguments seem to be a json/dict target that contains both single- and double quotes, and I can't seem to figure out how to construct it so that subprocess.Popen will execute it correctly.

The exact full command written into a command shell follows this format:

```
binary -a "something" -b "something else" -c '{ "230" : [{ "501193" : "190" }] }' -d "another something"
```

Note the quotes, especially after the `-c` flag that contains both singles and doubles. The command is very specific about them.

This is what I've been working on:

```
test = '{ "230" : [{ "501193" : "190" }] }'
subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/binary',
                '-a',
                '"something"',
                '-b',
                '"something else"',
                '-c',
                '{}'.format(test),
                '"another something"'],
                ).communicate()
```

Obviously the above leaves out the single quotes that are meant to enclose `test` but I have tried triple-quotes around it and experimenting with escape characters and other suggestions from Stackoverflow but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: `"'{}'".format(test)`

Comment: I’ve often had issues with Popen. I always end up going with shell=True and just passing the whole command as a string (of course you need to think about security/shell injection risks)

Comment: @OlvinRoght I had tried that earlier but the command still doesn't execute properly and I'm not sure why. It would be great if there was a way to make subprocess.Popen display the full command for execution. But if I replace subprocess.Popen with print() it shows that it tries to escape the single-quote ```'\'{ "230" : [{ "501193" : "190" }] }\''``` so I'm guessing that's what gets sent

Comment: @noob, it shows you quoted strings, cause you're printing *list of strings*. Try to print this statement separately and you will see that it works properly

Comment: @Cyberwiz I've considered ```shell=True``` but I prefer not. I'm hoping there's a way to get around this hurdle which surprisingly seems to be a bigger deal than I had expected.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Sure but either way the command doesn't execute properly...

Comment: I had a similar problem with a program that really really wanted certain parameters to have quotes around them. I found a workaround of adding a space to the end of my parameter, which presumably forced subprocess to quote it. Luckily the program I am calling didn't mind the extra space at the end of the parameter. Your mileage may vary.